# Move file from Documents to tmp XCode 8 iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10, nsfilemanager

I'm porting my application from **XCode7 and iOS 9.x to XCode8 and iOS10**.
I'm struggling with the handling of the files.

I need to download a file from my backend and after that to move it from `/Documents` to `/tmp`. Here is my code:

```
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = ...

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
        return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            ...
        } else {

            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            NSError *error;
            NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
            NSString *tmpPDFPath = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[response suggestedFilename] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]];

            if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:tmpPDFPath] == YES) {
                [fileManager removeItemAtPath:tmpPDFPath error:&error];
            }

            NSLog(@"readable %d", [fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:filePath]);
            // Print TRUE
            NSLog(@"tmpWritable %d", [fileManager isWritableFileAtPath:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpDirectory]]);
            // Print TRUE

            BOOL move = [fileManager moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:tmpPDFPath error:&error];

            ...
        }
    }];
```

Everything works fine if I run my application in an iOS 9.3 simulator, but the app crashes when run in an iOS10 one.
The first change I had to made is to pass to the `moveItemAtPath` method `filePath.absoluteString` instead of `filePath`.
Despite this editing, the move method always fails with this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“XXXX.pdf” **couldn’t be moved to “tmp” because either the former doesn't exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn't exist.**" UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/file:/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/24CAB2B2-F495-4CFF-90A7-5C51AF38C194/data/Containers/Data/Application/3D8EEEF9-F639-4D6C-BD5E-17A571F7B836/Documents/XXXX.pdf, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       **Move**
>   ), NSFilePath=/file:/Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/24CAB2B2-F495-4CFF-90A7-5C51AF38C194/data/Containers/Data/Application/3D8EEEF9-F639-4D6C-BD5E-17A571F7B836/Documents/“XXXX.pdf, NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/“XXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/24CAB2B2-F495-4CFF-90A7-5C51AF38C194/data/Containers/Data/Application/3D8EEEF9-F639-4D6C-BD5E-17A571F7B836/tmp/“XXXX.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b0a3500 {**Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"**}}

Has anyone already dealt with that kind of error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first workaround is to pass through the **NSData**:

```
 NSError* errorWrite = nil;
 NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath];
 BOOL write = [data writeToFile:tmpPDFPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&errorWrite];
```

This code works fine, but I would like to understand why the previous one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the solution for me was to update to the latest version of the Dropbox SDK (currently 3.2.0) from 3.0.15. In particular, I was still targeting iOS 8.x so my CocoaPods update was not picking up the newer versions of Dropbox and this error was fixed around version 3.0.18. See [this forum QA](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Objective-C-Downloading-a-file-No-such-file-or-directory/m-p/223940#M12078) for more details.